Performance Evaluation by New Supervisor when ex supervisor is still with the company?
I was told my performance evaluation would be conducted by my new supervisor (who has been with the company for the last 2 months).  My ex supervisor is still with the company in a different role but supervised me for 1 year.  My request to complete the PE with my ex supervisor was denied.  The HR department said that our current supervisors will be conducting the review getting feedback from the old supervisor.  My ex supervisor is happy to conduct the review.
I don't like this. The new supervisor knows nothing of my performance of the last year and is not in a position to evaluate me and my performance of that role, which I am no longer in, anyway.  My role changed in 2024 and my new supervisor knows nothing of my previous position or performance and HR won't get my old supervisor to complete the review.  How do I proceed?

"The HR department said that our current supervisors will be conducting the review getting feedback from the old supervisor." In short, your new supervisor will be getting feedback straight from your old supervisor to conduct the evaluation, why are you not happy with this arrangement?

Do you think you will be in a worse position when you wait until you actually know what the review says? It's hard to argue against a review you haven't even gotten yet, isn't it?

Please clarify: Is this only a performance evaluation in the narrow sense, or would the meeting include actions such as setting goals until the next performance evaluation, and a general discussion of what you like/dislike/what helps/disrupts your work etc.? If it's the latter, I'd argue this is all the more reason for the new supervisor to at least participate in this review.

Does this answer your question? Performance review with a manager who doesn't know me?

Pretty standard in my experience, your new supervisor should get the feedback as HR have suggested.
Go into it with an open mind, make sure you have thoroughly prepared yourself, particpate fully in the meeting - if you are still unhappy after that then is the time to go to HR.

I have experienced this myself, sometimes it works in your favor, sometimes not.
Now - generally, when a new supervisor comes along, they will have had some form of Handover from the previous one - and in that capacity will get a bullet-point brief of some of the teams rockstars and wins - if you have done good things in the past year - your new Supervisor will probably be aware of these.
You can help yourself by making sure you have the evidence and documentation to back yourself - so, say you worked on a project that saved the company a projected $10,000 per year - being able to have that to show the new Supervisor is to your advantage.
This can be especially useful if the Project had a number of speedbumps and so you get to omit the speedbumps or relay them more... diplomatically
So, do not be disheartened.
Where it has bitten me in the past is when the new supervisor does not want to award exceeds expectations (or whatever nomenclature your company uses) because they have not been there for a while - this has been especially frustrating if you have worked really last the past review period.
In which case - take this up with HR.

In most cases your performance review does not matter.  I bet this is true in your case as you recently filled a new position anyway.  Your past performance is only slightly indicative of how well you will do the new job.
This is very dependent upon the specific company, but most only care if you either "walk on water" (WOW) or are a total slug.  Everyone else gets a similar raise or bonus.  If you are a WOW type, then your raise/bonus will be slightly higher.  The difference is typically so small that it's not worth getting upset about.
Why do you think that the new manager will not follow the recommendations of the old manager?
For me, I had the opposite happen.  I started with a new manager in early January and the reviews happened in March that spanned the previous calendar year.  So, the old manager held my review with the new manager attending.  The old manager contradicted himself by using the same thing in the "ways to improve" and "ways that I am doing a good job".  When I confronted him on this, he did not have a good answer.
My new manager told me my eval was basically BS and the old manager was holding a bit of my raise to give to other people on the team.  (We are talking maybe .2% here.)  This generated a lot of good will with the new manager with the way I shrugged off.  I got a bigger than expected raise the next two years.  None of those amounts being life changing.  What did change my life for the better was having a good relationship with the new manager.
So, you can generate good will by just going with the flow and welcoming your new manager.

Very company dependent ...

It would be nice to see some evidence for "in most cases". "In most cases" where I've worked, for instance, it could affect your pay increase
